# 2D Global Map: 2 vertical axes, 1 horizontal

Tags: python, mapping

I want to create a global map that shows how runoff changes over time and over latitude. That means that on the 'x' axis I have my time period, and on my 'y1' (left axis) I have the latitude from -90 to +90 and on my 'y2'(right axis) I show my runoff values. This would create sort of a contour/density map

The input I have is an array with the following shape
roff = (60L, 360L, 720L) (time, latitude, longitude)

Any suggestion as of how I should proceed? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/index.html) library. You have an example with double y axis [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/two_scales.html).